# Parse binary data for c# bootp server?

Tags: c#, binary, binary-data, bootp

I need one of my C# .NET applications to act as a bootp server. The protocol is pretty simple but I dont know an easy way to build/parse the binary data.

Any ideas:
[image]
<sub>(source: [tcpipguide.com](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/diagrams/bootpformat.png))</sub>

Comment: I take it, by "easy" you are referring to something other than taking 0xFF, etc, and left shifting them by a number of bits defined by constants that map to the description of the areas in the above chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this. You might be able to play around with the [marshaling attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t2cwe11(VS.71).aspx) such as StructLayout to pack a structure into a byte array but this is probably tricky and not worth the effort.

You could use a specialized framework such as [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) to attribute a class in such a way that it will be serialized to match the structure you need.

But in my experience, the easiest, fastest, and most flexible method of creating a binary structure like this is to use a MemoryStream class to hold a buffer of byes, then use a [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) around it to actually write the binary data into the stream.

In any case, it helps to have a working server to reference. Use a tool like Wireshark or Microsoft Network Monitor to capture the wire traffic so you can compare your wire format to an example that is known to work.

Comment: great info!  Everything I've done so far in .NET is actually less than 64 bits, so it's nice to see other options in case I eventually need to do something like Tim (very likely).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple structure like:

```
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct MyData {
    public byte OpCode;
    public byte HardwareType;
    public byte HardwareAddressType;
    public byte Hops;

    public int TransactionId;

    public short Seconds;
    public short Flags;

    public int ClientIPAddress;

    public int CurrentIP;

    // all other fields in the required sequence  
}
```

and use the code from [this blogpost](http://dooba.net/2009/07/c-sharp-and-serializing-byte-arrays/) to serialize/deserialize packets. But there may be a problem with ServerName and BootFilename because of differences in encoding and probably you need to specify exact  FieldOffset for each of the fields (see [this topic on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) for details).
Hope this will help :)